# How to set a minimum distance for a bounding box?

Tags: javascript, geo

I've following bounding box:

```
    "minLon": "13.4446404",
    "minLat": "52.5097786",
    "maxLon": "13.4456404",
    "maxLat": "52.5097786"
```

Now the distance between the bounding box is 0.0676 km according to this function:

```
export const getDistance = (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit = 'K') => {
    if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
        return 0;
    }

    const radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180;
    const radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180;
    const theta = lon1 - lon2;
    const radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
    let dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    if (dist > 1) {
        dist = 1;
    }
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    if (unit == 'K') { dist *= 1.609344; }
    if (unit == 'N') { dist *= 0.8684; }
    return dist;
};
```

I would like to adjust the lat and long values equally (minLon,maxLat..) so that the distance is a minimum of 200m and does not exceed 220m.

How to do that?

**Desired output**

```
    "minLon": "13.4441404",
    "minLat": "52.5091786",
    "maxLon": "13.4459404",
    "maxLat": "52.5099886"
```

This has now a distance of 0.15km (I would need to iterate longer to get to 200m - but you get the idea) ;)

Comment: By distance, do you mean the diagonal? If yes, what do you mean by "adjust the lat and long values equally"? Could you give what the desired bounding box would be in your case with these 4 input values?

Comment: Yes. The diagonal distance needs to increase to a minimum of 200m. It should equally increase the 4 numbers to stretch the bounding box